# Misunderstanding of incrementation

Tags: perl

In Perl, I have this following code:

```
my $val = "0";

for(my $z = 0; $z <= 14; $z++)
{
    ++$val;
    if($val == 9) {
        $val = "A";
    }
    print $val;
}
```

it prints:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 A B 1 2 3 4 5
```

yet it's supposed to continue from B to C, from C to D and so on, what is the logic behind this?

Comment: btw, `for my $z (0..14)` is viewed as much clearer.

Comment: Important note: ALWAYS x 1,000 `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Comment: I'm a fan of `use diagnostics;` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) would have given you a warning message like:

> Argument "B" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $val = "0";

for(my $z = 0; $z <= 14; $z++)
{
    ++$val;
    if($val eq '9') {   #   <------------------
        $val = "A";
    }
    print $val;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To quote [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement):

> If you increment a variable that is numeric, **or that has ever been used in a numeric context**, you get a normal increment. If, however, the variable **has been used in only string contexts since it was set**, and has a value that is not the empty string and matches the pattern `/^[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*\z/`, the increment is done as a string, preserving each character within its range, with carry... *(emphasis added)*

`$val == 9` is a numeric context.  So it prints A (you just set it), and then you get the magic increment to B (it hasn't been used in a numeric context yet), but then you hit the `==` (using it in a numeric context), so when you get to `++$val` again B is treated as a number (0) and increments to 1.

You could use `eq` to make a string comparison, thus preserving the magic increment, but you could also just say:

```
print 1 .. 8, 'A' .. 'F';
```

Comment: Why doesn't that apply to the case when `$val` is 'A'?  It is true that `$val` "has ever been used in a numeric context", yet the increment yields 'B'.  According to the perlop excerpt, the existing behavior still seems mysterious...

Comment: Setting the variable resets the "ever been used" flag, as is made clear by the next sentence.

Comment: @recursive, yes, the doc is a little self-contradictory ("variable...ever been used" vs. "since it was set".  The "ever been used" is intended to mean the variable's value, not the variable itself; the value gets changed to A and the new value has not "ever been used in a numeric context" by the next increment, so it increments to B.